# Meaning of “playing of favorites”?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I am came across this phrase [in a CR presentation](http://www.calorierestriction.org/Pomerleau_Dean/CR_psychology_talk_files/frame.htm) (slide #19). What is its meaning?

> Equanimity – Less “**playing of favorites**” with people, compassion

Comment: The slide is saying that we should treat people equally (without favoritism) and with compassion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To 'play favorites' means to treat some individuals better or to prefer them, as when a teacher gives more attention to certain students or gives them better grades/marks than other students who have done the same quality work.

'Playing of favorites' is just a gerund variant of this idea.

Answer (score 3):

Right.  Note that the phrase is "play favorites", as in "George played favorites when he chose his team," and "George was known for playing favorites when choosing his team."  "Playing **of** favorites" is grammatical, but almost never the best usage.

Comment: Yes, and I believe that the 'of' variant is likelier when the gerund is used as the subject.